# Neumann's generator count

Tags: python-3.x

```
   list1=[8096, 5368, 3416 ,8963, 751, 6239 ,886, 3488, 2519, 1855, 2026 ,1461, 4587]
    for num in list1:
        random=pow(num,2)
        count=0
        equal=0
        while True:
            random = (random // 100) % 10000
            count+=1
            if random==num:
                break
            else:
                random=pow(random,2)
        print(count)
```

it should give the no.of counts it had taken to reach its actual value,but am unable to get the output

Comment: Are you sure this is actually something that is mathematically true? Where `random` can eventually become the same value as `num` again? The fact that your code doesn’t terminate tells me that it probably isn’t.

Comment: http://www.codeabbey.com/index/task_view/neumanns-random-generator  check this link ,"random = (random // 100) % 10000" this will truncates the value from "random=pow(random,2)"

Answer (score 3):

This is the [middle square method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle-square_method) for implementing a pseudorandom number generator.

A problem with the "middle square" method is that all sequences eventually repeat themselves.  It is possible, as you have found, that your code will not terminate for some inputs.  The 8096 input  in your example will eventually send you into a 6100 -> 2100 -> 4100 -> 8100 -> 6100 cycle, without ever visiting 8096 again beforehand.

The infinite loop here is not a problem with your code, but with the underlying algorithm.

Comment: An aside to your answer: a reasonably thorough treatment of PRNGs is given in chapter 7 of Averill Law's _Simulation Modelling and Analysis_. This starts with Von Neumann's mid-square method, and then goes on to discuss more sophisticated methods.